# Altium: How can I edit a component from a library

Tags: pcb, components, altium, library

I downloaded a library from the internet and I want to create a new  PCB component using the ones in the downloaded library with little editing/changes (such as the footprint). Is that possible? How?

Comment: Open the library. Copy a device, Paste it. Rename the copy and edit it as you like.

Comment: works for a PCB component too right? @ThePhoton

Comment: Yes it works almost the same. The option 'Paste 1 Components' (sic) will show up when you've copied the part to the clipboard.

Comment: @The Photon - Would you be so kind to post your answer so the question won't remain unanswered? :)

Comment: @BenceKaulics, I was hoping someone would come along and make an answer with nice pictures.

Comment: @The Photon - I see. I did not want to make one because actually you answered the question and I though it would be like taking your credit. But if you do not mind I could post an answer with nice pictures.

Comment: @BenceKaulics, no problem --- if you do the work of making pictures, you should get the credit.

Answer (score 7):

As @The Photon has already pointed out, you can copy any component from any library (PCB or Schematic) into your own library to modify them as you like.

---

1. Open the libraries

   [image]

---

2. Copy the specific component from the source library

   [image]

---

3. Once you have the component on the clipboard **Paste 1 Components** option will be available

   [image]

---

4. Finally, rename the copy

   [image]

---

And after these steps you can edit the component in your own library.