# Altium - Use an existing component symbol for another component

Tags: altium

Altium designer (without vault) only comes with through hole components (resistor, capacitor) in the component library. I want to design SMD capacitors and resistors on my own but I want to reuse the schematic symbol of the default Altium components. How can I do that?

Comment: Open schematic lib and copy the component or use the existing part and add another footprint so a resistor symbol will have both SMD and TH footprints. You can choose in the schematic which one you want to use.

Comment: The steps are the same only you have to apply it on .schlib. :http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/176589/altium-how-can-i-edit-a-component-from-a-library/176781#176781

Comment: I'm about 99% certain a stock altium install has symbols and footprints for SMT passives in most common sizes, somewhere. There are a ton of libraries available, even before the vault.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an Altium PCB library that contains all of your SMD footprints. Once you have your PCB library created, open the SCH library containing the symbols you want to reuse, select the part whose symbol you want, and open its properties (double-click it in the SCH Lib tab, or right-click it and choose "properties"). Then in the "Models" section at the bottom right of the properties window that pops up, use the "Add" button to add your footprints.

Comment: Woops, sorry Bence, didn't read your comment until after I posted this

Comment: No problem, I do not have much time nowadays for writing proper answer.